How to automate canvas window?
I am automating Java desktop applications and some windows designed with canvas in Java applications (AWT). Upon inspecting the window, I am not able to select particular options (box) since all the sub-elements are attached to one element, which refers to the main window.
The window displays information as lines, and the user can drag and drop the lines to change their positioning.
Are there any ways to automate this without using an image-based automation tool? If image-based automation is the only solution, which tool would be most reliable?

Here is a package for turning Areas into something (event-wise) akin to java.awt.Component: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/

Start with AreaManager

Thanks for your suggestion. It would be great if you can provide any example of how to implement this. Thanks in advance

There's a runnable example in AreaManager (Run the class)
